# Set results from jQuery (AJAX) into Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to show results from jQuery function into bootstrap modal? I have a table and when user clicks one specific column, the modal should be shown with appropriate data.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   function getBreak(breakid,pos,countrycode){
      $.ajax({
       url: "{{ url('getBreak') }}",
       type: "GET",
       data: "id="+breakid+"&pos="+pos+"&countrycode="+countrycode,
       success: function (result) {$('#myModal').modal('show');},
       error: function(data){
            alert("Error")
        }
      });
   }
</script>
```

And this is a very basic modal where I want to change insert the data.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to somehow append the modal with html content which I would get from `getBreak()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes possible use this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   function getBreak(breakid,pos,countrycode){
      $.ajax({
       url: "{{ url('getBreak') }}",
       type: "GET",
       data: "id="+breakid+"&pos="+pos+"&countrycode="+countrycode,
       success: function (result) {
       $('#divhtml').html(result);
       $('#myModal').modal('show');},
       error: function(data){
            alert("Error")
        }
      });
   }
</script>
```

and in the desiging you have to do this

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div id="divhtml"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. But I'm always getting the breakid of first element. And I've tried to add `data: "id="+this.breakid+"` and it doesn't work.

Comment: please checkout what data coming from your url

Comment: That is the problem. I always get the same id in onclick function...
`<div onclick="getBreak({{ $t->breakid}},{{ $t->position}},{{ $t->countrycode }});">` produces 1234 as id for all items

Comment: It works now. I selected the wrong column from db. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You could add this into you Success function, you could loop through the results data and add to the modal before you show it.

```
$.each(result , function(i, v) {
    $('.text1').text(v.id);
}
```